# Google App Engine Mapreduce query

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce, distributed-computing

So, I was wondering how this problem can be made to work on a Google App Engine mapreduce framework, or indeed if it can be made to work at all. So I have an input file that is split into multiple parts and stored up in the Google cloud. Now I want to run the same Python code on all the split up parts, and then combine it back in order into one output file. If I run my code on the input file without splitting it up, it takes around 20 minutes.

I basically do not understand the map-shuffle-reduce model.  It would be great if someone could explain it to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There was a nice talk on `Google I_O 2012` : **Introducing Google Compute Engine**, you may easily [find it on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-sF5ZWB_FY), it explains all the details and how to setup and how to get results.